# Kubernetes - Add a Windows node to a Windows-based control plane

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

I have installed Docker Desktop and Kubernetes on a **Windows** machine. 
When i run the `kubectl get nodes` command, I get the following output:

```
NAME             STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready    control-plane   2d1h   v1.24.0
```

So my cluster/control-plane is running properly.

I have a second Windows machine on the same network (in fact its a VM) and I'm trying to add this second machine to the existing cluster.
From what I've seen the control-plane node has to have kubeadm installed but it seems it's only  [available for Linux](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#:%7E:text=A%20compatible%20Linux%20host.%20The%20Kubernetes%20project%20provides%20generic%20instructions%20for%20Linux%20distributions%20based%20on%20Debian%20and%20Red%20Hat%2C%20and%20those%20distributions%20without%20a%20package%20manager.).

Is there another tool for Windows-based clusters or is it not possible to do this?

Comment: There are instructions with Kubeadm here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/adding-windows-nodes/

Comment: That guide is only for a linux-based control plane @MauricioPoppe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are details of docker desktop from docker documentation.

[Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/kubernetes/) includes a standalone Kubernetes server and client, as well as Docker CLI integration that runs on your machine. The Kubernetes server runs locally within your Docker instance, is not configurable, and is a single-node cluster..

You can refer [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/) and create kubernetes cluster with all your windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

The other windows machine can be joined into cluster. Please refer [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/) for windows and install kubeadm and run kubeadm join ,which will bootstrap and join the node into kubernetes cluster.

Comment: I already have kubectl installed, and I don't think there is any way to install kubeadm on a Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the control-plane can only run on a [Linux node](https://learnk8s.io/installing-docker-kubernetes-windows#:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20can%20run%20Windows%20and%20Linux%20containers.&text=And%20there%27s%20a%20further%20constraint,to%20operate%20correctly%20on%20Windows.).
I suspect that the output from the `kubectl get nodes` command was from a control-plane running on the WSL that Docker-Desktop uses.

So the only option for running a master node on Windows, is to run in a Linux VM.